# Functions of constant gradient norm on (incomplete) Riemannian manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry

I am interested in real-valued $ C^2$ functions $ f$ defined on a connected Riemannian manifold $\mathcal{M}$, such that the norm of the gradient is constant, i.e. $ \Vert \nabla f(x) \Vert = c > 0 $.

In a paper by Takashi Sakai, 'On Riemannian manifolds admitting a function whose gradient is of constant norm', there is a theorem that states that if $\mathcal{M}$ is a complete and connected manifold of non-negative Ricci curvature, then any smooth function which satisfies $ \Vert \nabla f(x) \Vert = c > 0$ is an affine function.

However, I am interested in a certain 'local' version of this, namely: given $ U \subset \mathcal{M} $, where $ \text{dim}(\mathcal{M}) = n $ and $ U $ is diffeomorphic to $ \mathbb{R}^n $, what sort of $C^2$ functions have the property that $ \Vert \nabla f(x) \Vert = c > 0, \forall x \in U $ ?

An observation from the same paper gives such an example. Namely, Remark 2.2 states the following:
[image: remark-2.2-sakai]

Are there any other functions which could locally satisfy the constant gradient norm property in such a way that $ U $ has dimensionality $ n $ (i.e. the gradient remains constant in all directions when moving away a little bit from some point $x$) ?

Comment: You are mistaken about the dimension of the domain $U$. By the say, one can also use $N$ which is not a hypersurface, say, a point, and achieve the same result.

Comment: The dimension of $\nu(N)$ is exactly $n= \dim M$, since it is a vector bundle of rank $\mathrm{codim} N = \dim M - \dim N$ over $N$.

Comment: Thank you both for your useful comments! I am just learning about these things and for some reason I didn't think of N possibly being just a point. The question still stands, though.

Comment: @AndreeaM In all cases, this works. Not just for $n$ being a point.

Comment: (The dimension of a rank $k$ vector bundle over a $d$-dimensional manifold is $d+k$. Hence, $\nu(M)$ has dimension $\dim N + (\dim M - \dim N) = \dim M$.)